# do dependencies in flutter make their own build.gradle and settings.gradle files?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

[image]

I am trying to publish second version of my app but it is showing to upgrade version in build.gradle file.
So do I have to upgrade all build.gradle files?

Answer (score 0):

If your project contains multiple modules, you may use the root (project-level) build.gradle file to keep configuration common to all modules.